# Accessing a website from multiple machines from same account even if they allow only single host

Tags: browser

We have a premium account in a job portal. This job portal provides access only from single browser session. But are we required to go through many profiles soon, and hence we need to open up several sessions from on same account on different browser and different machines. I know its kind against the portal's policy.

Comment: This is not possible. Only the last session will be active and previous sessions will be discarded.

Comment: Have you tried accessing the site from different connections? If so, using proxies might help - though whether this is morally acceptable is difficult to say, since you have not explained in your question why you must do this. Maybe you are taking more than you are paying for, and you just shouldn't do it?

Comment: thanks halfer, actually we are small startup. require to urgently build team in small time ( 4 - 7 days). We have purchased premium account but could able to fully exploit it.

Comment: Being a "small startup" doesn't usually make an organisation exempt from paying for their data consumption requirements. Perhaps this part of your business is not financially sustainable? (There are limited cases where I'd suggest a grey area applies, such as when _de facto_ monopolists are keeping data costs artificially high, or if there is a public interest defence in scraping. However the existence of such cases does not mean that mechanisms to work around API limitations can always be morally justified).